# Why dotless compilation in visual studio asp.net project is not working?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, dotless

I have installed nuget dotless package to my ASP.Net Visual Studio project. After the installation, I can see it added handlers to the web.config file, but there is no less compilation taking place. There is no error nothing, but .less file is not compiled. Is there any issue dotless compiler with the visual studio 2017? Can anybody give me some guidance here?

Comment: I've not tried dotless but I use [WebCompiler by Mads Kristensen](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler) for both `.sass/.scss` and `.less` with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. One issue was to delete the system.web handler entry for the dotless, as it is supposed to do with old iis server. The resolved the issue of 503 error, but the .less file was not still compiling. So I tried another option. I uninstalled the latest dotless 1.6.7 and installed dotless 1.5.2 version. This actually resolved the issue. It seems the latest dotless 1.6.7 server has some issues with iis server. Whenever I change the content of less file directly from the server, it is automatically compiled by the dotless.